# How to make the navigationBar's height became 22 with an animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want the navigationBar's height became 22 with an animation, my code like follow, why it doesn't work?

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, rect);
rect.size.height = 22;
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, rect);

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"scale"];
[animation setPath:path];
[animation setDuration:1.0];

[animation setAutoreverses:YES];
CFRelease(path);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a question like me on stackoverflow, that question's url is 
[Animating Frame with CoreAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039465/animating-frame-with-coreanimation)

They said frame can't changed with CAKeyframeAnimation.That maybe a bug, or CAKeyframeAnimation can't be achieved originally.

So long, i got no answer.Maybe my question unclear expression, or other reason.
So, end the problem in that status.